# GWT based open source ecommerce solution

Tags: java, gwt, e-commerce

Well, I have done a lot of research. But I could not find anything. Just [Broadleaf Commerce](http://www.broadleafcommerce.org), but they use GWT only for admin module.

**EDIT:**

Well, I know that GWT is not SEO friendly, but there are ways to make GWT applications SEO-friendly...

**Why it should be based GWT based? ..**

- Because, I have been in Java world for more than 12 years..
  My employer also choose and invested to Java technologies heavily..
- I do like and prefer strongly typed programming languages.. 
  Therefore JavaScript is not an option... I do not want to enter to a war between 
  strong versus weak typing languages. It is my preference due to my experiences...
- JSF or other server based Java Web frameworks requires much more server CPU and 
  memory resources per user comparing to GWT applications... And, they are not 
  cloud  friendly.

Comment: Why does it have to be GWT based? Whats your reasons? What have you searched for? What do you expect from it? You haven't really given us much info tbh.

Comment: "Why does it have to be GWT based?" I get annoyed when people try to micromanage my (or someone else's) motives in digging about a technology. I am going to up-vote this because it was down-voted and because it is a legitimate question.

Answer (score 3):

The biggest reason you won't find a widely adopted GWT-based ecommerce solution is because GWT, by itself, isn't very SEO-friendly. Since it's all Javascript, the crawlers don't get to see the DOM in the same way a user might. This is a big loss for ecommerce sites, because SEO is a huge driver of business.

There are, however, [ways to make your GWT app crawlable](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/).

Answer (score 2):

I work for Broadleaf Commerce.    The question was asked a while back but I thought it might be good to respond for anyone considering building the front-end of their eCommerce site in GWT technologies.

As mentioned in the question, Broadleaf Commerce does utilize GWT (or more specifically SmartGWT) in our admin.    As such, we've developed a number of JPA and component interactions that could be leveraged in a front-end that utilized GWT as well.

Overall, we prefer a GWT  for the admin as it supports the paradigms that we need to provide rich functionality in an extensible way.

We don't recommend building the customer facing eCommerce UI in GWT due to the heavy degree in which the look and feel of these UIs are customized.   Our customer's have found using GWT for the customer facing front-end to be limiting and complex.   We recommend using Thymeleaf (no relation to Broadleaf) for the front-end as it provides a way to share HTML code between developers and designers without the translation / rework steps required in typical JSP development.

That being said, if you are looking to build your front-end UI in GWT, there is quite a bid of middle-tier code that you could leverage from the BLC admin.